# How to use same javascript for multiple audio files on page?

Tags: jquery, audio, switch-statement

I'm having trouble duplicating this code on my page to work for several different audio file players. Is there a way to dynamically switch out the audio depending on which audio player I'm interacting with?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! It's my last step in making my full site work-- you can see the full site [here.](https://lizetteayala1211.github.io/skin-contact/)

```
var player1,onplayhead1,playerId1,timeline1,playhead1,timelineWidth1;
jQuery(window).on("load", function () {
    audioPlay();
    ballSeek();

});

function audioPlay() {
    /*var player = document.getElementById("player2");*/
  var player01 = $("#myAudio")[0];
  //alert(player);
    player01.play();
    initProgressBar();
    isPlaying1 = true;
}

function initProgressBar() {
  // jQuery(".play-pause").empty().text("PAUSE");
    player1 = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    player1.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeCal);
    var playBtn = jQuery("#play-button-container");
          playBtn.click(function() {
            if (player1.paused === false) {
                player1.pause();
                isPlaying = false;
              // jQuery(".play-pause").empty().text("PLAY");

            } else {
                player1.play();
                isPlaying = true;
              // jQuery(".play-pause").empty().text("PAUSE");
            }
          });

}

function timeCal() {
    var width = jQuery("#timeline1").width();
    var length = player1.duration;
    var current_time = player1.currentTime;

    // calculate total length of value
    var totalLength = calculateTotalValue(length);
  //console.info(totalLength);
    jQuery(".end-time").html(totalLength);

    // calculate current value time
    var currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(current_time);
    jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);

    var progressbar = document.getElementById("seekObj1");
    progressbar.style.marginLeft = width * (player1.currentTime / player1.duration) + "px";

}

function calculateTotalValue(length) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(length / 60);
      var  seconds_int = length - minutes * 60;
  if(seconds_int < 10){
    //console.info("here");
    seconds_int = "0"+seconds_int;
    //console.info(seconds_int);
  }
      var seconds_str = seconds_int.toString();
       var  seconds = seconds_str.substr(0, 2);
        var time = minutes + ':' + seconds;
//console.info(seconds_int)
    return time;
}

function calculateCurrentValue(currentTime) {
    var current_hour = parseInt(currentTime / 3600) % 24,
        current_minute = parseInt(currentTime / 60) % 60,
        current_seconds_long = currentTime % 60,
        current_seconds = current_seconds_long.toFixed(),
        current_time = (current_minute < 10 ? "0" + current_minute : current_minute) + ":" + (current_seconds < 10 ? "0" + current_seconds : current_seconds);
    return current_time;
}

function ballSeek() {
     onplayhead1 = null;
     playerId1 = null;
     timeline1 = document.getElementById("timeline1");
     playhead1 = document.getElementById("seekObj1");
     timelineWidth1 = timeline1.offsetWidth - playhead1.offsetWidth;

    timeline1.addEventListener("click", seek);
    playhead1.addEventListener('mousedown', drag);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

}


function seek(event) {
    var player = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    player.currentTime = player.duration * clickPercent(event, timeline1, timelineWidth1);
}

function clickPercent(e, timeline, timelineWidth) {
    return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline1)) / timelineWidth1;
}

function getPosition(el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}

function drag(e) {
    player1.removeEventListener("timeupdate", timeCal);
    onplayhead1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    playerId1 = jQuery(this).parents("li").find("audio").attr("id");
    var player = document.getElementById(playerId1);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', dragFunc);
    player1.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate);
}


function dragFunc(e) {
    var player = document.getElementById(onplayhead1);
    var newMargLeft = e.clientX - getPosition(timeline1);

    if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= timelineWidth1) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft < 0) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft > timelineWidth1) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = timelineWidth1 + "px";
    }
}

function mouseUp(e) {
    if (onplayhead1 != null) {
        var player = document.getElementById(playerId1);
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragFunc);
        player1.currentTime = player1.duration * clickPercent(e, timeline1, timelineWidth1);
        player1.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeCal);
        player1.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate);
    }
    onplayhea1 = null;
}

function timeUpdate() {
    var player2 = document.getElementById(onplayhead1);
    var player = document.getElementById(playerId1);
    var playPercent = timelineWidth1 * (player1.currentTime / player1.duration);
    player2.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
    // If song is over
    if (player1.currentTime == player1.duration) {
        player1.pause();
    }

}
```

Comment: *Is there a way to dynamically switch out the audio depending on which audio player I'm interacting with?*  I dont understant what you want....could you precise and give a sample with mulitple audio player??

Comment: @Frenchy What I mean is, is there a way to use the function above multiple times on a page to play 6 different audio files. As of now, I've changed the naming conventions slightly, but it will only play one audio file + not the rest.